# Google map view how can i get original point or frame for annotation while map zoom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i set custom annotation pin in map on the click of annotation i get call for this method

```
(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0)
```

in that method i want to open popover so i want frame form (MKAnnotationView *)view i get right frame while map in normal mode.

but when i zoom map and click on annotation at that time i get wrong frame at that time the x and y value is big, so any solution for that any offset or zoom factor i get so i divide according to that so i get actual frame of annotation.

Comment: Show the code you have in that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGPoint annotationPoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate 
                                   toPointToView:mapView];
float boxDY = annotationPoint.y - 35;
float boxDX = annotationPoint.x - 1;
CGRect box = CGRectMake(boxDX, boxDY, 1, 1);
[popoverControllerDetail presentPopoverFromRect:box 
                                         inView:mapView 
                       permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|
                                                 UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|
                                                 UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight) 
                                       animated:YES];
```